# java jackson mapper convert unix timestamp to date, result wrong

Tags: java, json, unix, jackson

I'm trying to use jackson mapper to deserialize a Json File, one of the field in the json file is a unix timestamp, this is part of the json look like:

```json
    "shipment": {
        "shipDate": 1518040533
    }
```

This is the how the mapper works in action:

```java
        InputStream inputStream = this.getclass().getResourceAsStream(pathToFile))
        return mapper.readValue(inputStream, dataClazz);
```

The unix timestamp should be : `Wednesday, February 7, 2018 9:55:33 PM`

But after deserialization, it turned out to be: `Sun Jan 18 13:40:40 UTC 1970`

Any idea if this is jackon mapper's fault?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jackson doesn't interpret that as unix seconds, it interprets it as milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: you should multiply the seconds to 1000 to get the actual java date. It worked for me

Comment: Thank for the input, any idea I can customize the behavior of Jackson mapper multiply 1000 by itself?